# Jquery get class and use in function

Tags: jquery

html

```
<div id="one" class="bubble"></div>   
<div id="two" class="bubble"></div>  
<div id="three" class="bubble"></div>
```

Jquery

```
 $(function () {

              function bubble ()
              {
                 $(this).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
              }
            }); 
            $( document ).ready(function() {
               $(.bubble).bubble();
            });
```

I'm not really good with jquery, now what i'm trying to do is to fadein and fadeout the elements with class bubble, what's going wrong?

Comment: `$(".bubble").each(bubble);` might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing it as a parameter:

```
function bubble (el)
{
    el.fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
}
bubble($('.bubble'));
```